# Loop a Stylus command in Elixir

Tags: javascript, gulp, stylus, laravel-elixir

I have switchable themes and colors for my site, and I need Elixir/Gulp to render all the possible theme-color combinations as CSS files. Here's my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    elixir = require('laravel-elixir'),
    stylus = require('laravel-elixir-stylus'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

var themes = [
    "alpha",
    "beta"
];

var colors = [
    "blue",
    "red",
    "green"
];

if(elixir.config.babel)
    elixir.config.babel.enabled = false;

elixir(function(mix) {
    for(ti = 0; ti < themes.length; ++ti) {
        for(ci = 0; ci < colors.length; ++ci) {
            mix.stylus([
                'colors/'+colors[ci]+'.styl',
                'themes/'+themes[ti]+'/main.styl'
            ], "public/css/"+themes[ti]+"."+colors[ci]+".css");
        }
    }
});
```

To me, it looks like this should run. I tested the loop, and I know it goes through every theme-color combination just fine.

However, when I run it, it creates a folder `beta.green.css`, inside of which are two files, `main.styl` and `green.styl`.

1. How do I make this generate all of the Stylus commands, and not just the last one?
2. How do I make it combine the results in a single file, and not two separate files in a folder?

Comment: If you want to include multiple files in the directory, use `*.extension`.

Comment: But the idea is that I need to have multiple files going to multiple destinations. Includes inside the main.styl handle getting all the other files, but what I need is for each iteration of the for-inside-a-for to generate its own destination file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually ended up ditching Elixir altogether and just doing it in pure Gulp;

```
gulp.task('styles', function(cb){
    async.each(themes, function(theme, done) {
        async.each(colors, function(color, next) {
            gulp
                .src([
                    './resources/assets/stylus/colors/'+color+'.styl',
                    './resources/assets/stylus/themes/'+theme+'/main.styl'
                ])
                .pipe(stylus())
                .pipe(concat(theme+"."+color+'.css'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
                .on("end", next);
        }, done);
    }, cb);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe `laravel-elixir-stylus` shouldn't be called multiple times? (Or maybe, this is a bug … if you look at the [end of the implementation](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-stylus/blob/1df7b48129ca5a7c4393d081f083c4d057886ea5/index.js), you can see that tasks are being queued with the name `stylus`, probably overwriting each other) – so only the last one queued (`beta` + `green`) gets executed.
2. The second argument to `mix.stylus` is an output directory, pass in just `"public/css/"` instead of `"public/css/"+themes[ti]+"."+colors[ci]+".css"` if you don't want separate output folders.

"*To me, it looks like this should run. I tested the loop, and I know it goes through every theme-color combination just fine.*" – if you tested the loop outside the call to `elixir`, can you put in a `console.log` and see what gets triggered when you run the task?